# Ошибка при вызове share sheet

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller, bottom-sheet

Я создал xib для UIView. В нем  при помощи кнопки я делаю скрин и пытаюсь поделистся им с другими. Ранее у меня это было рализовано на UIViewController и все работало. Теперь в экшене который я прикрепил снизу ошибка.

> **Error : Use of unresolved identifier 'present'**

```
@IBAction func ShareContentAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentView.frame.size)
        contentView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        var imagesToShare = [AnyObject]()
        imagesToShare.append(image!)

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imagesToShare , applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.contentView

         // Здесь ошибка
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Не могу понять, на какой метод здесь нужно заменить `present` , ведь он да ViewCOntroller, а мне нужно это же на UIView

Comment: Теперь я точно никогда не буду учить swift, код просто ужасный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
if let controller = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    controller.present(
        activityViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

А можно через ViewController для этой View.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно !